# implication of lacking ind-cca security

Tags: public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, helios, elgamal

I was wondering if somebody could tell me what the impication is of an encryption scheme lacking ind-cca or ind-cpa security.  For example, the ElGamal scheme is known to lack ind-cca security.  The Helios voting protocol uses ElGamal to encrypt each ballot - what I am have a difficult time understanding is what the implication is of ElGamal having an efficient ind-cpa adversary and ElGamal being used in Helios.

Comment: You should probably move this to [Crypto Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).